# ErrorException : implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters

Tags: php, laravel

Am running Laravel 5.8 and getting this error when seeding

```
Seeding: CategoriesTableSeeder
```

> ErrorException  : implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters

> at /Users/saly/Sites/Saly/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Provider/Lorem.php:95

```
91|
92|         $words = static::words($nbWords);
93|         $words[0] = ucwords($words[0]);
94|
95|         return implode($words, ' ') . '.';
96|     }
97|
98|     /**
99|      * Generate an array of sentences
```

```
  Exception trace:

  1   implode(" ")
      /Users/saly/Sites/Saly/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Provider/Lorem.php:95

  2   Faker\Provider\Lorem::sentence()
      /Users/saly/Sites/Saly/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:222

>  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

The app is passing tests just fine in CI using PHP 7.3 and 7.2 so the problem might be PHP 7.4 in my local machine "OSX"

Here's my seed file

```php
<?php

use Saly\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CategoriesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(Category::class, 3)->create();
    }
}
```

And the factory

```php
<?php

use Saly\Category;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $name = $faker->sentence(4, true); // Here maybe?
    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'slug' => sluggify($name),
    ];
});
```

I think the problem is in the line where `sentence()` is used but I can't tell how to solve it because I just copied that line from the Faker docs

What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This has already been fixed in the most recent version of Faker.  In your error it says

```
> 95| return implode($words, ' ') . '.';
```

but if we look at [line 95 of the source](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/blob/master/src/Faker/Provider/Lorem.php#L95) we see:

```
> 95| return implode(' ', $words) . '.';
```

So, all you need to do is pull the latest version of Faker, probably by doing

```
composer update fzaninotto/faker
```

Comment: Exactly. It literally tells you to swap the parameters, easy!

Answer (score 15):

You can swap (in affect lines with `implode` command) glue and array.

Example:

```
return implode($words,' ') . '.';
```

to

```
return implode(' ',$words) . '.';
```

also, The newest version of the `fzaninotto/faker` package solves this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I am using php 7.4 with apache2,mariadb 10,yii2 advanced. Update your faker using below command

```
composer update fzaninotto/faker
```

and

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

then it:this error and

Error (#32)

An internal server error occurred.

The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.

Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

Fixes the issue.

Comment: I cannot decipher this. Is it meant to answer the question? It seems to quote something, but I am not sure what. It seems to say thanks. But I am not sure for what. It seems to describe a problem, but that would not be an answer. It seems to desccribe steps, but only in the context of describing a probelm. What is this?

Comment: from where did you copy this ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Answer (score 2):

This is happend for backward version of **fzaninotto/faker**. Update your faker using below command

```
composer update fzaninotto/faker
```

Comment: This command returns:
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I am using php 7.3 and 7.4 using homebrew.
I have two projects one is using 7.3 and other is using 7.4.

If I run project with 7.4 which requires 7.3 then same issue occures. when I change php version to required version (7.3) then it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is not Laravel related issue. It is due to new versions of PHP disallowed the use of previously used implode method.

Here is how I fixed it in PHP:

1. Create a function:

   function HA_implode($value1,$value2){

   ```
        if (is_array($value1)) {
            return  implode($value2, $value1);
        } else {
            return  implode($value1, $value2);
        }

    }
   ```
2. Now simply rename all functions in the PHP script from implode to HA_implode and you are done

This is useful in scripts where impode is commonly used as per the previous method and changing all the code can be a time wasting problem. So simply rename all implode functions using find / replace option of any PHP or text editor.