# join(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters

Tags: php, laravel

Am running Laravel 5.4 and getting this error

> join(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the
> parameters
>
> in SlugService.php line 137

```
return join($sourceStrings, ' ');
```

Comment: use `return join(' ', $sourceStrings);`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541888/errorexception-implode-passing-glue-string-after-array-is-deprecated-swap

Comment: If your issue is that you're using https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable you need to use version 4.4+ but that doesn't work with Laravel 5.4 so you probably need to either upgrade, or look for another library or downgrade your PHP version to one that doesn't show that deprecation notice

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
return join(' ', $sourceStrings);
```

Or if it is a file from some package, just update your package.

```
composer update ...
```

Comment: it's correct, when I use it ...     return join(' ', $sourceStrings);

Comment: That's nice. If you resolve the problem remember to upvote/check answers which were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting `glue` first in the function arguments?
Right now, you are trying to glue a space using `$sourceString`.
Try this:
`join(' ',$sourceStrings)`